# Tandy 1000 TDYSPKR utility

Tags: ms-dos, sound, audio, tandy-1000

I've seen reference to a TDYSPKR (.EXE or .COM?) tool that sets audio output options on the early Tandy 1000 series of computers (1000, 1000A, 1000SX, 1000TX, maybe others). Apparently it can toggle the internal speaker and audio output independently.

Does anyone know where to find this utility? Currently I'm running a BASIC program (that does `BEEP OFF` and `SOUND ON`) in my autoexec.bat. Starting BASIC is slow and I'd like a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it! TDYSPKR.ZIP is attached to a [post on the VCFed forum](https://forum.vcfed.org/index.php?threads/new-tandy-1000-sx-user-with-problems.17608/#post-238057). Registration is required to download.

Here is TDYSPKR.ZIP in base64 so it's not lost to time:

```
begin-base64 644 tdyspkr.zip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====
```

SHA256: `2970a630f4913b9b78d0b06d016989092c42d95c72eff9d1d6aa6cfff969b290`